# SpeechSynthesizer speaks the same text unless application is restarted in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, text-to-speech

I have implemented text to speech conversion in asp.net with the help of my question in [How to use windows speech synthesizer in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47300251/how-to-use-windows-speech-synthesizer-in-asp-net-mvc).

The text is converted to speech and stored in a file Voicespeech.wav. The browser plays the voice. Once the application is stared, I enter text and submit and it is spoken. But for every next text also the browser speaks the same first text. But when I checked the voice file with windows media player, the voice had been replaced with new text. How can I make it speak the new text entered?

Also every time I refresh the browser, it plays the voice. I want it to be played only for the button click. And each time, the text entered in the input box should be played, not first entered text after starting debugging.

I hope the question is understandable. Code is below.

> ApplicationController.cs

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> TTS(string text)
    {
        // you can set output file name as method argument or generated from text
        string speech = "speech";
        Task<ViewResult> task = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            using (SpeechSynthesizer speechSynthesizer = new SpeechSynthesizer())
            {
                speechSynthesizer.SetOutputToWaveFile(Server.MapPath("~/Voice/Voice") + speech + ".wav");
                speechSynthesizer.Speak(text);

                ViewBag.FileName = speech + ".wav";
                return View();
            }
        });
        return await task;
    }
```

> TTS.cshtml

```
<div>             
   <form action="~/Application/TTS" method="post">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Enter Text</label>
        <input type="text" name="text" class="form-control" id="searchbar">
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Speak</button>
   </form>          
</div>
```

**I believe the fault is here.**

```
<div>
 <audio autoplay="autoplay" src="@Url.Content("~/Voice/Voice" + ViewBag.FileName)"></audio>
</div>
```

Comment: This is because your browser is caching the file. Your should add a dummy parameter in the query string which change each request.

Comment: Well, you should know what "browser caching" is - because browser tends to cache file once it's loaded. You can set a viewmodel with parameter to differentiate each speech request or using partial view to load audio file for each POST request.

Comment: Thanks. I will work on that.

Comment: You can try with meta tag: `<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />` or `[OutputCache(Duration = 0, NoStore = true)]` attribute in `TTS` action method.